# What are these holes?

Tags: identification, pests, insects

I noticed these burrows on my lawn. The holes are 1/2”.  Pests? If so, what kind?

FWIW I live on Long Island, NY.

[[image: closeup]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are probably cicadas, or perhaps emerging bees or other insects. The female lays eggs and covers them up, then the insect goes through the larval stages underground, finally to emerge as adults when they dig themselves out. Very inconsiderate to leave such piles of subsoil, however.

Clemson U has an [interesting fact sheet](https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/holes-in-the-lawn/) on holes in lawn areas.

Comment: Not a cicada, they leave a clean hole. These holes have sand around them from excavation.

Comment: Small enough to be cycads or bees. The different color around the hole is just because the soil underneath is different, regardless of which insect dug the hole. It may have been a thin layer of lawn over sand.

Answer (score 1):

In my area (I'm not sure about yours), they could be wasps, or spiders. I've seen holes similar to that for a number of kinds of animals.

I'm pretty sure they're not any any kind of pest.